# Are there anonymous contributions to physics with large impact?

Tags: physics

Based on this question
[Are there any anonymous contributions to mathematics that had a great impact?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/are-there-any-anonymous-contributions-to-mathematics-that-had-a-great-impact) , I would like to ask the same question for physics. Physics is different from mathematics in the sense that you need to experiments in order to move on, so I guess an anonymous contribution would be much harder.

Looking at the examples of the mathematics thread, I wonder if a 4chan equivalent post (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/13394/6609) on particle or cosmology could ever be taken seriously.

Are there anonymous contributions to physics with large impact in the history of the field?

Answer (score 1):

Sophie Germain basically invented the theory of elasticity, but published under a pseudonym.

Comment: there's more to read about that in (at least) two answers to [Are there any anonymous contributions to mathematics that had a great impact?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3001/3869)